# Google Apps Script getSheetByName returns null when using a variable as argument

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that is set to run whenever a trigger is sent, and it needs to sort through the data it receives to determine which sheet to write data to.

I used to hard-code it with the exact names and it worked fine, but now I'm trying to make it easier to scale. Variable `value` in the switch should be a number.

Below is a snippet of the code.

```
var myIds = [111, 222, 333, 444];
var myUsers = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'];

...

switch (param) {
  case 1:
    break;
  case 2:
    for (let i = 0; i < myIds.length; i++) {
      if (value == myIds[i]) {
        userName = myUsers[i];
        break;
      }
    }
    userName = 'ETC';
    break;
}

if (userName != 'ETC') {
  let inSheet = 'In '  + userName;
  let outSheet= 'Out ' + userName;
  if (checkIn == true)
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(inSheet));
  else
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(outSheet));
}
else
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ETC'));
```

Rather than going to their respective In / Out sheets, everything goes to the ETC sheet instead. Some other times, there would not be any change on the sheets at all. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could explain why this happens, in addition to the question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The `break;` inside your `for` loop only breaks out of the `for` loop, not the `case`. So you break out of the `for` and end up on `userName = "ETC";`, which overwrites any value the loop may have set.

Instead, you can use `indexOf` or `findIndex`:

```
case 2:
    const index = myIds.indexOf(value); // Or `.findIndex(id => id == value)` if you need `==` not `===`
    userName = index === -1 ? "ETC" : myUsers[index];
    break;
```

If you really wanted the `for` loop, you could assign `userName` before the loop, so that the loop overwrites `"ETC"`:

```
case 2:
    userName = "ETC";
    for (let i = 0; i < myIds.length; i++) {
        if (value == myIds[i]) {
            userName = myUsers[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
```

---

Side note: I recommend avoiding parallel arrays like `myIds` and `myUsers`. It's really easy to end up updating one and not the other. Instead, consider an array of objects:

```
const users = [
    {id: 111, name: "aaa"},
    {id: 222, name: "bbb"},
    {id: 333, name: "ccc"},
    {id: 444, name: "ddd"},
];
```

Then the first example above would use `find`:

```
case 2:
    const user = users.find(({id}) => id == value);
    userName = user ? user.name : "ETC";
    break;
```

In a *really* modern environment with optional chaining and nullish coalescing, you could change `userName = user ? user.name : "ETC";` to `userName = user?.name ?? "ETC";` but there's nothing wrong with the conditional version.

---

Side note 2: You've used `let` within your `for` loop, so you seem to be using the more modern GAS that supports ES2015+ features. I suggest not using `var` in new code, always use `let` or `const`.

Comment: thanks for the great answer! I would like to expand on the original question though, where now after putting everything in an array of objects, when i try using `getSheetByName("In " + users[i].name)`, it returns an error saying that it can't read the property 'name' of undefined. I have the `users` array as a global variable so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Shironats - The problem there isn't `users`, it's `users[i]` -- or more specifically, that `i` is not a valid index into the `users` array. I can't tell you why not, because I have no idea what the value of `i` is there. But that line of code doesn't exist in the question or answer. You'd still use `userName` there, not `users[i].name`; it's just how you set `userName` that changes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I cleared up that problem. However, now that I'm using the `find(({id}) => ...` method, I'm not getting any new input even though logically things should go into the 'ETC' sheet. Still currently trying to figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was in another part of the code that I did not include in the question, where I re-initialized the userName variable every loop. This caused the userName variable to be undefined in some loops, in turn causing the `getSheetByName` function to return an error.